# Separate dataframe into individual dataframes based off one column

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

I need to create separate dataframes out of this one based off of the age column.
So one that shows all baby and then respective lengths and location, then teens with lengths and location and so on. Doing this so I can create three separate paired histograms so you can compare baby west vs. east, teen west vs. east, and adult east vs. west.

```
Age   Length    Location
Baby    5.6      West
Teen    8        East
Adult   12       East
Adult   6        West
Baby    4        West
```

I tried

```
ggplot(graph, aes(x= Length, color = Location)) +
  geom_histogram(fill="white")
```

but need it separated so its only for one age group instead of all together.

Comment: `group_split()` gave you exactly what you needed: a list of separate data frames. You want them in a list, that's easier to manage. Just plain `split()` would work fine too.

Comment: ```ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes(x = Age, y = Length, fill = Location), position = "dodge", stat = "identity")``` Are you looking for this? You don't need to split the data.

Comment: Splitting is easy enough with `split`, but if the only reason you're splitting it is to be able to split histograms by `Age` within `ggplot2`, then just simple grouping should work just fine as M-- already suggested. Don't split if you don't need to do anything else in a list format.

Comment: ggplot(graph, aes(x= Age, color = Location)) +
  geom_histogram(fill="white"). Looking to do this but with each individual age group. Eventually put it into R shiny where changing age group input to receive different histogram.

Comment: @reilly461 you may benefit from reviewing principals of the `ggplot2` package and reviewing this [Cheat Sheet](https://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/UG/SM/STAT3022/r/current/Misc/data-visualization-2.1.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

baby_df = df %>%
filter(age == "age")

Comment: Based on the example data the OP provided, your code returns `Error in 'filter()': ℹ In argument: 'age == "age"'. Caused by error: ! object 'age' not found`. Please ensure you test your answers to make sure they work. Thanks